# Integrated webcam not working in Juno 5.0 on Dell XPS 9550

Tags: release-juno, camera, webcam, dell

I am coming from Ubuntu 18.10 where everything was working, the webcam does not seem to be detected in Juno. There is no on/off key for the webcam on the XPS as far as I know. The webcam is enabled in the BIOS and I always update to the latest versions from Dell.

Stock Camera app gives me a dark window while auto brightness in Settings, which I believe is governed by the webcam, does not seem to work.

I tried `sudo modprobe -a uvcvideo` to no avail.

`lsblk` gave me uvcvideo 0, I think it means Juno is not starting the webcam.

Thank you, I am a Linux newbie, any help is very much appreciated.

Update: when opening the Camera app, there is now the following message, while before there was just a black window.

[image]

Comment: I think it's a specific problem in the camera app. I own a Dell XPS 9360 and also have issues with the camera app in Juno. I installed the gnome app `sudo apt-get install cheese` as an alternative.

Comment: Does Skype works by any chance?

Comment: Post there please:
https://github.com/elementary/camera/issues/87 We need more people registering the issue to gain traction!
Same issue on an Dell Inspiron 7559. Thanks!

Comment: i have the same problem in hp elitebook 8560w

Comment: Same on Dell Latitude E7470, I didn't had the problem on Elementary OS Loki.

Comment: Same issue on Dell Inspiron 5576. Other camera apps work, but Elementary OS Camera doesn't see camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native Camera app on Juno go updated some time ago, now all is working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I have a dell e7250 and same issue with the stock camera app. Cheese worked fine. Should submit a bug to github

Comment: Ok, thank you for your input guys. I would gladly submit the bug, but where is the appropriate place to do so to maximise visibility on it?

Comment: I suppose, you can start here https://github.com/elementary/camera

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on a 17" MacBookPro 6.1 - Cheese works fine as well and is the best solution around to replace camera apparently